# Type 'ChatViewController' has no member 'showOrHideKeyboard'

Tags: ios, swift

I can't seem to find the function I made.

> Error: Type 'ChatViewController' has no member 'showOrHideKeyboard'

Code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.defaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ChatViewController.showOrHideKeyboard(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.defaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ChatViewController.showOrHideKeyboard(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@IBOutlet weak var contraintToBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!

func showOrHideKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardInfo: Dictionary = notification.userInfo {
        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { () in
                self.contraintToBottom.constant = (keyboardInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.height
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }) { (completed: Bool) -> Void in
                //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should mark the selector method with `objc`

Change this line

```
func showOrHideKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {
}
```

to this line

```
@objc func showOrHideKeyboard(_ notification: NSNotification) {
}
```

Comment: @JohnDoe Have you added objc for showOrHideKeyboard method?

Comment: @JohnDoe Answer has been updated Please check and accept the answer.

Comment: um the answer is still the same? and that don't work

Comment: @JohnDoe Please check method declaration. For your info check edit history

Comment: Keep in mind the underscore `_` if you don't put it, it will not work

Comment: @JoseTomas Check my method declaration

Comment: I was answering to @JohnDoe actually

Answer (score 0):

Use either this:

```
@objc func showOrHideKeyboard(_ notification: NSNotification) 
#selector(ChatViewController.showOrHideKeyboard(_:))
```

Or:

```
@objc func showOrHideKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {
#selector(ChatViewController.showOrHideKeyboard(notification:))
```

Notice the `_` in function signature and `#selector`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that #selector with function name but no arguments name "(_:)" is no longer supported in swift lastest versions.

Just replace fill the arg name or use autocomplete to type the declaration:

```
#selector(ViewController.showOrHideKeyboard(notification:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimise your code like below

In ViewDidLoad()

```
[NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
         NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide].forEach { (notificationName) in
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notificationObservered(notification:)),
                                                   name: notificationName, object: nil)
        }
```

Create a function

```
// MARK: - Notification Observered
    /// Notification received
    @objc func notificationObservered(notification: NSNotification) {

        switch notification.name {
        case NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow:
            break
        case NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide:
            // let info = notification.userInfo!
            // let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
           break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```